# How to write relational database table about set blacklist?

Tags: database, datatable

If user_A want to set his own blacklist, how do I write?
Now I have a table about this:

```
Table: user_data
==========================
user_id | u_name   | ...|
==========================
000001 |  user_A   | ...|
==========================
000002 |  user_B   | ...|
==========================
000003 |  user_C   | ...|
==========================
```

Answer (score 0):

You may create a blacklist table with user_id as the foreign key to user_data.
For example:

```
Table : blacklist
blacklist_id: primary key
user_id: foreign key
blocked_user_id: the user is blocked by this user (foreign key)

| blacklist_ID | user_id | blocked_user_ID
+--------------+---------+----------------+
| 01           | 00001   |   00002        |
| 02           | 00001   |   00003        |
| 03           | 00001   |   00004        |
| 04           | 00002   |   00001        |
| 05           | 00002   |   00003        |
| 06           | 00002   |   00004        |
```

`Select blocked_user_ID from blacklist where user_id='00001'` will return a list :

```
00002
00003
00004
```

Comment: Excuse me I'm a freshman for these, i have a question that if user_B and user_C also need to set blacklist, and user_A、user_B、user_C they all have at list 10 user in there own blacklist,then i can user your method too ?    Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Yes, the backlist table keeps backlists for all users, and are distinguished by the foreigh key user_ID. There may be duplicate user_id in this table. Whenever you need to access the blacklist for a certian user, you can query that table using user_ID: `Select * from blacjlist b where b.user_id=12345`.

Comment: I got it, Thanks very much. And I have more one question,is there exist two attribute in one table like this:                       table: blacklist                                                [user_id | blacklist_event |user_id]                                    I am appreciated for your help!

Comment: why there are 2 user_id? It is not allowed with 2 same column names.What do you want to do?

Comment: I wish one user_id is the user who set blacklist, and the other user_id is the user who will be blocked and i want this user_id to relational with user_data table. so that is not a way?

Comment: Yes, you may have 2 or more foreign keys in one table. No problem.